# How can I know what's the largest number from a while loop in python?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

so far what I've done is this:

```
from random import randint    
def num_random():
    counter = 0
    while (counter <= 99):
       counter=counter+1
       base=randint(1,100)
       height=randint(1,100)
       area = base*height/2 
       data(area)

def data(area):
    print("area=",area)

num_random()
```

but I want to determinate what triangle has the largest area.

I thnik I could store the value of each area in a list and then use max(list), so I can know what is the largest. The problem is that I'm not sure how to store the values from the while loop in a list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, simply append `area` to a list, then call the `max` function:

```
from random import randint    
def num_random():
    counter = 0
    areas = []
    while (counter <= 99):
       counter=counter+1
       base=randint(1,100)
       height=randint(1,100)
       area = base*height/2 
       areas.append(area)
    data(max(areas))

def data(area):
    print("area=",area)

num_random()
```

---

```
>>> num_random()
('area=', 4140)
>>> num_random()
('area=', 4464)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
max(randint(1,100)*randint(1,100)/2 for i in range(100))
```

or if you want to make it a little clearer,

```
def area_triangle(base, height):
    return base*height/2

def max_rand_area(num_trials=100):
    return max(area_triangle(randint(1,100), randint(1,100)) for i in range(num_trials))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write the original code, plus being in list format:

```
from random import randint  
def num_random():
    base = []
    height = []
    area = []
    for i in range(99):    #Use For Loop rather than while loop with counter
       base.append(randint(1,100))        #Add value to "base" list
       height.append(randint(1,100))      #Add value to "height" list
       area.append(base[i]*height[i]/2)           #Calculate Area h*b/2
       print("Area = {}".format(area))     #Print Area Value to Terminal
    print("Max Area = {}".format(max(area))
num_random()  #call the function
```

In addition, now you can use index i to pull indexed values from the created lists.